# Why does shr eax, 32 not do anything?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

When running this assembly code(nasm)

```
mov eax, 0x12345678
shr eax, 32
```

I noticed that this did not 0 out the eax register, and I am confused on why is that?

I tried shifting by other numbers and indeed that worked as expected.

Comment: Since the Intel 186 or 286, shift counts are masked with 31 so your 32 is in effect a count of zero. On amd64 systems, shifts on 64-bit registers will work as expected up to the count of 63 instead.